# Java XML to Array

Tags: java, xml, arrays

Is there a function in java to convert a XML, which comes from an InputStream, into an Array?

Thanks for Answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at xstream - http://x-stream.github.io/. Very easy to use library to convert XML into java objects.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't. An XML is a tree datastructure that has no trivial translation to a flat array.

Of course you can write this function yourself, if you know what you want. Also there are many 3rd party libraries that allow conversion from XML to Java objects, but it's hard to recommend one without knowing what your problem exactly is.

Comment: My Problem is, that special characters aren't showed in my output string. And I had hope to show the special characters with converting to an Array.